# tcolorbox: option for "listing outside (but ABOVE) text"

Tags: listings, tcolorbox

The `tcblisting` environment provided by the `tcolorbox` package allows one to

1. display LaTeX codes in the lower part of a tcbox and the output in the upper part of the *same* tcbox, using the `text and listing` option:
   [image]
2. or display LaTeX codes in a tcbox on the left, and the output *outside* that tcbox on the right, using the `listing outside text` option:
   [image]

### Is it possible to have...

- the LaTeX codes in a tcbox at the bottom ***and***
- the output *outside and centered above* that tcbox?

---

### Codes for the above two pictures

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcblisting}{text and listing,center upper}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \path[fill=yellow!50!white] (0,0) circle (11mm);
  \path[fill=white] (0,0) circle (9mm);
  \foreach \w/\c in {90/red,210/green,330/blue}
  {\path[shading=ball,ball color=\c] (\w:1cm) circle (7mm);}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{tcblisting}

\begin{tcblisting}{listing outside text,center lower,righthand width=3.5cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \path[fill=yellow!50!white] (0,0) circle (11mm);
  \path[fill=white] (0,0) circle (9mm);
  \foreach \w/\c in {90/red,210/green,330/blue}
  {\path[shading=ball,ball color=\c]
    (\w:1cm) circle (7mm);}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{tcblisting}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I follow the suggestion of karlkoeller and will add new options `text above listing` and `listing above text` to `tcolorbox` (upcoming version 2.52 or above).

**UPDATE:** The options are part of `tcolorbox` starting with `version 2.60 (2013/12/17)`. The updated code for the example is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcblisting}{text above listing,center lower}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \path[fill=yellow!50!white] (0,0) circle (11mm);
  \path[fill=white] (0,0) circle (9mm);
  \foreach \w/\c in {90/red,210/green,330/blue}
  {\path[shading=ball,ball color=\c]
    (\w:1cm) circle (7mm);}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{tcblisting}

\begin{tcblisting}{listing above text,center lower}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \path[fill=yellow!50!white] (0,0) circle (11mm);
  \path[fill=white] (0,0) circle (9mm);
  \foreach \w/\c in {90/red,210/green,330/blue}
  {\path[shading=ball,ball color=\c]
    (\w:1cm) circle (7mm);}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{tcblisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Glad to have suggested new options for such a beautiful package :-)

Answer (score 8):

Such an option seems not to exist in the documentation.

So I've tried to create a new one called `text above listing` with the following code:

```
\makeatletter
\def\tcb@inputlisting@out@textAboveListing{%
  \tcb@inputlisting@out@prepare%
  \tcbdimto\tcb@w@outside{\tcb@width}%
  \tcbdimto\tcb@w@inside{\tcb@width}%
  \begin{tcb@sbsfloat}\begin{minipage}{\tcb@width}%
  \iftcb@lowervisible\tcb@minipage{\tcb@w@outside}\color{\kvtcb@collower}\kvtcb@fontlower\kvtcb@before@lower\ignorespaces%
    \tcbuselistingtext\unskip\kvtcb@after@lower\endminipage\fi\par\vspace*{10pt}%
  \tcb@minipage{\tcb@w@inside}%
  \begin{tcolorbox}[width=\tcb@w@inside,nobeforeafter,nofloat,sidebyside=false]\tcbuselistinglisting\end{tcolorbox}%
  \endminipage%
  \end{minipage}\end{tcb@sbsfloat}%
}
\tcbset{%
  text above listing/.code={\let\tcb@inputlisting\tcb@inputlisting@out@textAboveListing}%
}
\makeatother
```

Using it in your MWE

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\makeatletter
\def\tcb@inputlisting@out@textAboveListing{%
  \tcb@inputlisting@out@prepare%
  \tcbdimto\tcb@w@outside{\tcb@width}%
  \tcbdimto\tcb@w@inside{\tcb@width}%
  \begin{tcb@sbsfloat}\begin{minipage}{\tcb@width}%
  \iftcb@lowervisible\tcb@minipage{\tcb@w@outside}\color{\kvtcb@collower}\kvtcb@fontlower\kvtcb@before@lower\ignorespaces%
    \tcbuselistingtext\unskip\kvtcb@after@lower\endminipage\fi\par\vspace*{10pt}%
  \tcb@minipage{\tcb@w@inside}%
  \begin{tcolorbox}[width=\tcb@w@inside,nobeforeafter,nofloat,sidebyside=false]\tcbuselistinglisting\end{tcolorbox}%
  \endminipage%
  \end{minipage}\end{tcb@sbsfloat}%
}
\tcbset{%
  text above listing/.code={\let\tcb@inputlisting\tcb@inputlisting@out@textAboveListing}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{tcblisting}{text above listing,center lower}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \path[fill=yellow!50!white] (0,0) circle (11mm);
  \path[fill=white] (0,0) circle (9mm);
  \foreach \w/\c in {90/red,210/green,330/blue}
  {\path[shading=ball,ball color=\c]
    (\w:1cm) circle (7mm);}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{tcblisting}

\end{document}
```

yields:

[image]

You can adjust the separation modifying the value `10pt` inside the code.

It is not perfect, but that's the best I can do... I suggest you to make a feature request for this...